# HTML/PHP - Promocode Use Limit

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, database

So I have a website where you can register and use a specific registration code. However I want to limit the total use of the registration code to only 20 times. So the first 20 people who use it will get it, and then it'll be locked out meaning no one else can use the registration code. So if I have this input field:

```
Registration code: <input type="text" id="registration_code">​
```

Then I just want to grey the field out, or make it unclickable when the limit has been reached. My idea on how to do this would be to have an ajax call for the text field, which calls a php file that checks the number of times it is used already. The way it would do that is, I would have a specific 1-column table in my database that starts at the value of 0 and increments everytime the code is used. The php can retrieve that number and if it's `<=20` then lock else, leave it open.

However, this seems like a very roundabout method, and I was hoping stack had some better ideas. Anyone know how to best deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: Produce 20 different codes. when a page is requested select one (expired=0 requested=0)and show it to the use (set requested=1). If user registers it by submitting update column expired=1 else expire user session and set requested=0. You can achieve all this in php, without involving ajax. I know it looks complicated.

Comment: @Ertunç yah..could you repeat that in a different way, I'm not sure I entirely understand

Comment: I said it reads complicated. But it saves you from maintaning code in clientside. In your way you would have to develop code to request if there are remaining codes that are not registered. Say you show same registration code to 20 people and none submitted back yet. What will you show 21st user. In my way you may show him m requested n submitted. He can be candidate. You may even write to his session, when one of the first 20 sessions expires without submitting back.